# How do you change the DNS servers on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: dns, raspberry-pi

I am trying to change the DNS servers on a Raspberry Pi (running Raspbian). I tried `nano /ect/resolv.conf` and then put in `nameserver 8.8.8.8` (Google DNS), but it does not appear to have been applied. What do I need to do to change the DNS servers used for name resolution?

Comment: That's the correct place and the configuration is also correct. No need to do anything else. Still not resolving?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to edit the scripts that reside in

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts
```

The one that you are interested in will be

```
ifcfg-[yourinterfacename]
```

In this file, add entries for

```
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
```

A reboot will update `resolv.conf` and the active network configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a typo in your command, try `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`.
The `ect` folder is not a valid folder.